# Rstudio (version 1.0.44) printing plots takes a lot longer than previous versions

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I installed the new Rstudio 1.0.44 on Windows 7 64 bits. I also upgraded to R 3.3.2 at the same time. Now, rendering of complex ggplot figures is taking a lot longer than in previous version. Problem is quite noticeable when using transparency (alpha) parameters.
I've also getting plots have rendered and getting the following  warning:

```
Warning message:
In names(gp) : reached elapsed time limit
```

Any insights on this would be great.
thanks

Comment: Please, can you [edit] the Q and add the operating system you are using? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the the issue was caused by the git version control. When disabled in the options, the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there have been several reports of general performance decreases with recent RStudio releases, some of which may have been resolved in the daily builds, which you can find here before they reach stable release: https://dailies.rstudio.com/