# R: "reached elapsed time limit" Warnings

Tags: r, rstudio

I keep getting "reached elapsed time limit" warnings at various locations of my code. I have recently updated my MacOSX to Catalina which created issues with R. I think that might another one of them as I did not have these issues before. As part of solving these issues, I have just uninstalled/reinstalled R & RStudio completely so they are both fresh installs up-to-date.

Some examples of Warnings:

> Warning message:
>   In getNamespace("grDevices") : reached elapsed time limit

or

> Warning message:
>   In structure(class = c("unit.list", "unit"), do.call("c", lapply(x,  :
>     reached elapsed time limit

I unfortunately do not think a reproducible example will be useful here. The code sometimes throws a Warning, sometimes not. If I close RStudio and restart it it will not throw the Warning. Some other fixes (mentioned here: ["reached elapsed time limit" errors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247102/reached-elapsed-time-limit-errors-in-r) and https://community.rstudio.com/t/reached-elapsed-time-limit-warnings-rstudio/36647) like `dev.off()` and `gc()` seem to temporarily fix the issue as well. It is something about R and/or RStudio on my machine.

How do I permanently fix this?