# Anomalies plot in r with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create an "anomalies graph" (not sure if this is the correct name, but that's how I've found it everywhere) and I am trying to following this guide here

http://lenkiefer.com/2017/12/11/plotting-u-s-macroeconomic-trends-with-fred-and-r/

I changed the code because I need a mid point of a set value (200) and not a zero, and now it looks something like this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(scales)
library(tibbletime)

YRBP<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
RM50<-c(213, 241, 243, 252, 219, 210, 198, 180, 187, 188, 171, 192, 194, 200, 201, 213, 234, 235, 269, 210, 234)
ACC<-data.frame(YRBP, RM50)
ACC <- mutate( ACC, 
               up2=ifelse(RM50>200,RM50,200),
               down2=ifelse(RM50<200,RM50,200)
)


G<-
ggplot(data=ACC, aes(x=YRBP,y=RM50))+
geom_line(color="black")+
theme_bw()+
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=200,ymax=down2),fill="#4575b4",alpha=0.5)+
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=up2,ymax=200),fill="#d73027",alpha=0.5)  +
geom_hline(yintercept=200,color="black")+
scale_color_manual(values=c("#4575b4","#d73027"),name="Snow Deposition Rate")+
scale_x_continuous()+
scale_y_continuous()+
labs(x="Year (BP)", y="Snow dep. rate")+
geom_rug(aes(color=ifelse(RM50>=200, ">=200","<200")), sides="b")
G
```

The problem is... well, for once it seems to only plot it once every couple of times, and R gives me errors like

```
Warning message:
In pushgrobvp(x$vp) : reached elapsed time limit
```

The first part varies, but there is always a "reached elapsed time limit" warning. 
Second of all... I really don't care about showing the legends in the plot (it should appears to the right of the plot) because I'm going to describe what's going on anyway without relying on a legend on the graph, but I need to have axis labels, something that it doesn't appear, at all, in the plot I'm trying to do.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine on my machine. No warnings. For a similar problem and some options to fix see https://community.rstudio.com/t/reached-elapsed-time-limit-warnings-rstudio/36647 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247102/reached-elapsed-time-limit-errors-in-r. PS: If you don't need a legend "add" `+ theme(legend.position = "none")`.

Comment: Mind that the dataset I am using is 3500 rows long (but i can't upload it here)

Comment: I see. But then its hard to reproduce your issue. I just checked with a dataset where I increased the sample size to 3500 rows by simple random sampling from the given example data. But still your code works fine. ):

Comment: And by the way. it's still just a warning and no error. If found a similar issue here: https://ourcodingclub.github.io/tutorials/tidyverse/ . Near the end of the page, just above the map, the author refers to the warning "Warning message:
In drawGrob(x) : reached elapsed time limit" with the words "We are working with thousands of records, so depending on your computer, making the map might take a while. This message doesn’t mean something is wrong, just lets you know that generating the map took a bit longer than what RStudio expected." So it may be an issue related to your machine.

Comment: Perfect! I'll try to run it on my work PC and not my personal laptop when I'll get the chance then!